# sharepoint api - file content encoding problem

Tags: rest, sharepoint, character-encoding, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to get a pdf file content array from one of my sharepoint libraries and encode it to base 64
now it works with this ajax request:

`$.ajax({   url: "/sites/pae/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<url>')/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true",   type: "GET",  binaryStringResponseBody: true,   success: function(data){ console.log(data) },   error: function(data){console.log(data)}   });`

but the problem is that it returns a string with unrecognizable characters which makes it impossible to convert to base64

Is there a way to decode it from utf8 or to bring it directly with base64?